# Find where many to many is empty or condition in related not match

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

Here's my database (simplified) :

```
User
    @ManyToMany
    List<Section> sections;

    public static Model.Finder<Long,User> find = new Model.Finder<Long, User>(Long.class, User.class);

Section
    Integer year;
    @ManyToMany
    List<User> users;

    public static Model.Finder<Long,Section> find = new Model.Finder<Long, Section>(Long.class, Section.class);
```

Using Ebean, I need to list all Users that don't have any sections related to them for this year (2012) (so, also including those who don't have any section related to them at all).

But I can't see how I would do this.

I tried :

```
User.find.where().isNull("sections").findList(); // but it didn't worked
```

So I'm stuck here. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have the same problem, Do you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
String q="find * fetch sections where sections.id is null"

Ebean.createQuery(User.class,q).findList();
```

This will create a left outer join query, the find.where().IsNull("sections") doesn't work.